# vim syntax highlighting of ColdFusion hash marks

Tags: vim, coldfusion, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a patch for `cf.vim` to resolve an issue with hashes.  In ColdFusion, `#` signs are used to enclose an expression inside a `cfoutput` block.

```
<cfset x = 1 />
<cfoutput> x is now #x# </cfoutput>
<!--- outputs "x is now 1" --->
```

The problem comes into play when there is a lone `#`, not inside a `cfoutput` block:

```
<a href="#x">an anchored link</a>
```

This will cause vim to highlight everything after the `#` as if it were in a `cfHashRegion`.

```
syn region cfHashRegion start=+#+ skip=+"[^"]*"\|'[^']*'+ end=+#+ contained containedin=cfOutputRegion contains=@cfExpressionCluster,cfScriptParenError

syn region cfOutputRegion matchgroup=NONE transparent start=+<cfoutput>+ end=+</cfoutput>+ contains=TOP
```

Is there something I can add to `cfHashRegion` to tell vim "Don't enter a cfHashRegion unless the start and end properties are both found?

Super-bonus: `cfoutput` is only the most common way to be in a "cfOutputRegion".  Any `cffunction` with output="true" will behave as if everything inside its block were wrapped in `cfoutput` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `syn match` instead of `syn region`? I don't know the ColdFusion syntax, so I won't know if this is possible/correct.

Something like:

```
syn region cfHashRegion "L\=#[^#]+#" containedin=cfOutputRegion  contains=@cfExpressionCluster,cfScriptParenError
```

You may also want to look into the use of the `contains=ALLBUT,{group-name},..` argument list for some cases.

Comment: I had to escape the +, but it worked.  It isn't perfect, because a `cfHashRegion` can actually be split over multiple lines.  In practice though, they are almost always on a single line.  Thanks!

Comment: I added this to my Vim plugin for better CF support https://github.com/davejlong/cf-utils.vim